# @Post returning 400 Bad Request using Rest

Tags: android, json, rest, http-post, gson

I've created an application which Logs a user in when they supply a valid username and password and I am trying to get the application working with an api.

For some reason, when I try post the URL, I get returned a 400 Bad Request error. I believe it is because my parameters aren't being attached to my request correctly.

Here's it my Rest Post:

```
@Rest(converters = {GsonHttpMessageConverter.class})
@Accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface UserApi {
    void setRootUrl(String rootUrl);

    @Post("/xxx/xxx/{name}/{password}")
    public LoginResponse login(String name, String password);

}
```

Here is my LoginResponse:

```
@Data
public class LoginResponse {

    private String result;
    private String api_key;

}
```

I start off all the calls when I click a button, username and password are sent to the login. Then this LoginResponse object is created:

```
public void login(String userName, String password, Handler<LoginResponse> handler) {
    try {

        String newapi = "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/";
        userApi.setRootUrl(newapi);
        LoginResponse response = userApi.login(userName, password);
        execute(handler, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I can see in my REST Post Build file that the username and password parameters are being put in with the request. See code below:

```
 public LoginResponse login(String name, String password) {
    HashMap urlVariables = new HashMap();
    urlVariables.put("name", name);
    urlVariables.put("password", password);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json")));
    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
    return (LoginResponse)this.restTemplate.exchange(this.rootUrl.concat("xxx/xxx/{name}/{password}"), HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, LoginResponse.class, urlVariables).getBody();
}
```

When I call the URL: It takes on the form `http://xxxxxxx.com/xxx/xxx/john/password`. Where john and password are the information that I entered in the login form.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help shed any light on this problem. Thanks

Comment: I encountered this scenario where  our backend is deployed having http setup instead of https.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give that a go on monday.